# How to correctly read the value of html <input> from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

The title is basically it. I am trying to read the user input in the html  element using javascript.

This is not an duplicate to any existing question because numerous existing answers suggested just reading the "value" of the input.

i.e.

```
const input_value = document.getElementById('input_id').value;
```

However, this is not correct, when you print the 'input_value' it gives you a blank line in the javascript console.

Does anyone know the CORRECT way of reading the content typed by the user.

Link to the fiddle -  https://jsfiddle.net/2sazrcyp/

Comment: It is correct only. See **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/02bnued6/7/)**. Also, I am guessing you want the value when user starts typing. If this is the case then there is a concept called ***[event-handling](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)*** that you want to take a look.

Comment: This is a duplicate question because you totally left out [event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: @mandy8055 Hi, thanks for explaining, just to clarify I am accessing the value only when the user click a button so the .value is invoked in a click listener callback so the <input> is already populated.

Comment: @J.C.Stark looks like there is some issue in your code which is not reflecting in question. Can you please create a minimal fiddle which replicates your issue and attach that to your question ?

Comment: @J.C.Stark show me your eventHandler please. There are two types of event that you want to read up on. [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) and [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event). I am hoping one of them will serve your purpose

Comment: @Vivek Tikar Hi please see the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2sazrcyp/. One thing I  did not realise which might be affecting the code is that my <input> is created dynamically using document.createElement and directly assigning properties. When I create the element by just appending string literal of the html (i.e. div.innerHTML += '<input>') and getting the element back using getElementById, it seems that reading the .value then worked. I am now reading about the relationship between dom attributes and properties but still pretty confused.

Comment: @J.C.Stark, I have deleted my old answer and posted new one based on fiddle that you provided. Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: @J.C.Stark, I pasted your fiddle link in the question. Can you please correct the fiddle contents by using minimal working code, You can use `non working snippet` that I added in my answer below. This will help future visitors and stop other people from downvoting your question.

Comment: @Vivek Tikar. Thank you, I have minimized the fiddle and try to get rid of unrelated code. However, I think the onchange function isn't the cause and I added it because i thought this was what you meant by testing the event handling in your deleted response, now I deleted that one in the fiddle as well. Please find the updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/JCStark/0zdbay16/1/

Comment: @J.C.Stark Fiddle is still throwing errors as, `btn_template`, `input_field_template` are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

So the code is not wrong but the implementation is.

### The problem

When you do

```js
const input_value = document.getElementById('input_id').value;
```

This means **take the current value in the input and store it to the constant `input_value**. And since the current value at the start is empty string, empty string is being stored, and even after changing the value in web page, it is not being updated.

### Solution

The  solution is simple. Just store the element in a constant and fetch the value only when needed.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input_id'); // this stores the input element

// fetch when needed - example use:
input.addEventListener('input', () => { console.log(input.value) };
```

I hope this clears it. If not comment below. else select as answer plz

Comment: Please refer fiddle in latest comment in comment section of question to understand actual ask. Actually question alone isn't very clear.

Comment: @VivekTikar I think I got it right, cuz during beginner stage I also faced this problem....

Answer (score 0):

```
let input = document.getElementById('input').value;
```

I use this in the code for a searchbar, it works well

Comment: Please refer fiddle in latest comment in comment section of question to understand actual ask. Actually question alone isn't very clear.